# Cannot use notification in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am sending a notificatioin from this Broadcast reciver which is triiggered by an alarm manager to send sms but i cant see any notification.

I also tried to include sent intent and delivery intent but cant use registerReciever here.

Here is my Code.

Broadcast Reciever

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String SENT="sent";
    public final String tag="com.example.pritesh.smstimer";
    public MyReceiver() {

    }

    //@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.i(tag,"Sending");
            NotificationManager notificationManager=  (NotificationManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1=new Intent(context,Time_Picker.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent1,0);
            Notification.Builder notification=new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("SMS SENT")
                    .setContentText("Your SMS has Been Sent")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(Time_Picker.Phone,null, Time_Picker.Message, null, null);
            notificationManager.notify(0,notification.build());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Sms Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/favicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Time_Picker"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".noti"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>


</application>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors or warning in logcat?

Comment: can you add your manifest file to the question?

Comment: wait adding and no i didnt get any error in logcat

Comment: You need to set the status bar icon. On your `Builder`, call `setSmallIcon()` with whatever you're using for that.

Comment: Thank you everyone il try it and tell.

Comment: Thank you guys its working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the receiver in your androidmanifest.xml or called registerReceiver to do the same? I don't think it will work until you do.

See here:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

Comment: Yes i have registered the reciever but still i was not able to use register reciever. It showed cannot resolve registerReciever(anonymous.android...)